# DAX low performance when referencing the same measure two times

Tags: performance, powerbi, dax

I designed a set of measures, that in the end should allow me to calculate sales amount w/o cancelled transactions and with discounts

Here are the definitions for those measures:

```
define measure Sales[Amount] = SUM(Amount)


define measure Sales[Discounted Amount] = CALCULATE(
    ABS(SUM(Sales[DiscountValue] ) ),
    FILTER(
        VALUES( Sales[SalesOrderSource] ),
        Sales[SalesOrderSource] = "XXX"
    ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Sales, SalesInvoiceDate[SalesInvoiceDate] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Sales, SalesOrderDate[SalesOrderDate] ) --
)

define measure Sales[Cancelled Amount] = CALCULATE(
    ABS([Amount]),
    FILTER( VALUES( 'Sales' ), Sales[Status] = "Cancelled" ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Sales[InvoiceDate], SalesInvoiceDate[SalesInvoiceDate] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Sales[OrderDate], SalesOrderDate[SalesOrderDate] ) --
)


-- RUNNING EXTREMELY SLOW
define measure Sales[AmountNet] = CALCULATE(
    [Amount] - [Cancelled Amount] - [Discounted Amount],
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Sales[InvoiceDate], SalesInvoiceDate[SalesInvoiceDate] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Sales[OrderDate], SalesOrderDate[SalesOrderDate] )
)
```

Unfortunately, the performance of the final measure **Sales[AmountNet]** is very slow.

BUT when I remove the [Cancelled Amount] factor from the [AmountNet] definition, it performs well. I suspect it's because of referencing the same measure ([Amount]) two times, where the second reference is overloaded with the FILTER iterator.

I would like to get some support on understanding this behaviour and how this could be rewritten to achieve better performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
define measure Sales[Cancelled Amount] = CALCULATE(
    ABS([Amount]),
    KEEPFILTERS( Sales[Status] = "Cancelled" ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Sales[InvoiceDate], SalesInvoiceDate[SalesInvoiceDate] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Sales[OrderDate], SalesOrderDate[SalesOrderDate] ) --
)
```

My hope is that this approach will be less expensive than FILTER over VALUES(Sales).

Comment: This is a good suggestion and should be roughly the same as `FILTER( VALUES( 'Sales'[Status] ), Sales[Status] = "Cancelled" )`. The important part is filtering on a single column rather than using `VALUES` on a whole `Sales` table (not a great idea).